# TikZ - diagram of the sun

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am attempting to generate the following diagram:

[image]

I am finding it difficult to place all of the triangles surrounding the center circle in the manner shown. Currently I can place four of the 8 triangles by specifying left, right and so on but I don't know how to place the triangles that are slanted. How would I go about completing this diagram?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code you already have? That makes it easier for others to come up with a solution (setting up the framework is not that much fun).

Comment: You can either `rotate around` the midpoint of the circle, calculate the path of the rotated triangles by hand or even use the `isosceles triangle` shape.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's something in `tikz` which is similar to what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]
    \draw (5,0)
        arc (0:360:5);
    \foreach \angle in { 0,45,...,360 }{
        \draw [rotate around={\angle:(0,0)}]
            (5.5,0)    
            -- +(0,-1.5)
            -- +(3,0)
            -- +(0,1.5)
            -- cycle;
       }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Taking @Qrrbrbirlbel's comment into account and adding color and thickening the lines, you could write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm,line width=4pt,draw=yellow]
\draw (1,0) node[draw,circle,minimum size=5cm] (TheSun) {};
    \foreach \angle in { 0,45,...,359  }
    {
        \draw [rotate around={\angle:(TheSun.center)}]
            ($(TheSun.center) + (5.5,0)$)
                   -- +(0,-1.5)
                   -- +(3,0)
                   -- +(0,1.5)
                   -- cycle;
     }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To give you:

[image]

The benefit of this last approach is you can easily change the location of the sun by rewriting

```
\draw (1,0)
```

to any value you want, say

```
\draw (3,-4)
```

and everything else will follow.  Though, if the sun is the only thing you're drawing, this feature will have no apparent effect.

## Styles

You can modify the style of the parts of the sun and `tikz` has a very nice interface to allow you to do this such as naming your style in meaningful manner.  In this example, I create two styles:  one for the flames and one for the body of the sun.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
    sunflames/.style={
        line width=1pt,
        draw=red,
        fill=yellow,
        regular polygon, 
        regular polygon sides=3,
        inner sep=0.35cm
    },
    sunbody/.style={
        line width=2pt,
        draw=red,
        fill=yellow,
        circle,
        minimum size=5cm
    }
 }
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]
\draw (1,0) node[sunbody] (TheSun) {};
    \foreach \angle in { 0,45,...,359  }
    {
        \draw [rotate around={\angle:(TheSun.center)}]
            ($(TheSun.center) + (7,0)$)
            node[shape border rotate=\angle-90,sunflames] {};
     }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `circle` path is probably easier: `\draw (0,0) circle[radius=5];` It may be even more maintainable if you use a `circle` node (`\node[draw,circle,minimum size=5cm] (c) {};`) and then use `c.center` as the point to `rotate around`. Also, you have two triangles at the angle of `0`/`360`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel.  Thank you!  Very good points.

Answer (score 16):

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle(0,0){2}
    \multido{\i=0+45}{8}{\uput{5pt}[\i]{\i}(2;\i){\pspolygon(0,0.5)(0,-0.5)(1,0)}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

If you don't like `\uput`, use `\rput` as follows,

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle(0,0){2}
    \multido{\i=0+45}{8}{\rput{\i}(!2 5 72.27 div 2.54 mul add \i\space PtoC){\pspolygon(0,0.5)(0,-0.5)(1,0)}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

If you don't like `\pspolygon`, use `\pstriangle` as follows,

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle(0,0){2}
    \multido{\i=90+45}{8}{\rput{!\i\space 90 sub}(!2 5 72.27 div 2.54 mul add \i\space PtoC){\pstriangle[dimen=middle](0,0)(1,1)}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

If you only like `\pstriangle` and `\uput`, use them as follows,

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle(0,0){2}
    \multido{\i=90+45}{8}{\uput{5pt}[\i]{!\i\space 90 sub}(2;\i){\pstriangle[dimen=middle](0,0)(1,1)}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

**Note** that `\pstriangle`  sets `dimen=outer` (changable) by default while `\pspolygon` sets `dimen=middle` (unchangable). Unfortunately, you cannot change `dimen` for `\pspolygon` so I change `\pstriangle`'s `dimen` to `middle` to be the same as the `\pspolygon`'s `dimen`.

You can prove that all my variants above produce the same output by compiling the following and view them alternately.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}

\SpecialCoor
\psset{dimen=middle}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle(0,0){2}
    \multido{\i=0+45}{8}{\uput{5pt}[\i]{\i}(2;\i){\pspolygon(0,0.5)(0,-0.5)(1,0)}}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle(0,0){2}
    \multido{\i=90+45}{8}{\uput{5pt}[\i]{!\i\space 90 sub}(2;\i){\pstriangle(0,0)(1,1)}}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle(0,0){2}
    \multido{\i=0+45}{8}{\rput{\i}(!2 5 72.27 div 2.54 mul add \i\space PtoC){\pspolygon(0,0.5)(0,-0.5)(1,0)}}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle(0,0){2}
    \multido{\i=90+45}{8}{\rput{!\i\space 90 sub}(!2 5 72.27 div 2.54 mul add \i\space PtoC){\pstriangle(0,0)(1,1)}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

**Animated version:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}

\SpecialCoor
\psset{linecolor=orange}

\begin{document}

\multido{\n=0.0+0.1}{6}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle*(0,0){1}
    \multido{\i=0+45}{8}{\uput{5pt}[\i]{\i}(!1 \n\space 1.5 mul add \i\space PtoC){\pspolygon*(!0 0.25 \n\space add)(!0 -0.25 \n\space sub)(!0.5 \n\space2 mul add 0)}}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```